# Why do I need to explicitly putchar (' ') in this code?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am working through Kernighan & Ritchie and have got to exercise 1.9. In fact I wrote some code which appears to solve the exercise, and I have tested it on Windows (with Git Bash and gcc) and Termux (with clang) by piping in a line with a variable number of spaces e.g. `echo " one  two   three"`, and the expected output comes out i.e.  `one two three`.

I got to the solution by trial and error, though it is the same as the solution provided by Lvictor on the [clc wiki](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_1:Exercise_9).

The code I wrote myself is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
/* Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank. */
    
int main () {
    int c;
    
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ' ) {
            }
            putchar (' ');
        }
        putchar (c);
    }
}
```

What I find perplexing is why I need the `putchar (' ');` line. I do not understand why the value of c is not `' '` after the program exits the if statement. Originally I did not have this line, but then the program removed all spaces from the input, to my surprise.

As I am a beginner C programmer, maybe there is something I don't understand about the scope of variable values, though it seems to me that if the value of c is `' '` when the if statement starts, and if it is `' '` in the second while loop, it should also be `' '` when both exit, but this does not appear to be the case.

I have Googled K&R exercise 1.9, which is how I found the wiki above, and looked at other quesions concerning this exercise on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've cleaned up the indentation to highlight the control flow. The short answer is that the internal loop _swallows_ one or more contiguous SP characters. Once that is done, the perplexing `putchar( ' ' );` outputs a single SP.

Comment: In case you didn't notice the discussions on Meta SO relevant to the K&R tag: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425747/2057969) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425749/2057969).

Comment: @Fe2O3 (and John Bollinger); I'm a defender of the `kernighan-and-ritchie` tag

Answer (score 5):

The **two** instances of `getchar()` make it difficult to handle EOF correctly.

The following is an alternative that may be easier to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    int c;
    int SPfound = 0;

    while( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF ) // Note single "entry point" for data
        if( c == ' ' ) // swallow and flag one or more contiguous SP's
            SPfound = 1;
        else {
            if( SPfound ) // if any SP's, output a single one.
                putchar( ' ' );
            putchar( c ); // output the non-SP character.
            SPfound = 0;
        }
}
```

Notice that this would "trim" any *trailing spaces* fetched prior to EOF. You can consider if you want the program to add a single trailing SP to represent those.

**EDIT:**
Not happy to leave it, here's another version that uses less code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    for( int c, prev = 0; ( c = getchar() ) != EOF; prev = c )
        if( !( c == ' ' && prev == ' ' ) ) // output when NOT consecutive SP's
            putchar( c );
}
```

This outputs the *first* of any series of SP's encountered, but suppresses the 2nd, 3rd, ...

Comment: If there were trailing blanks before the EOF, you'd probably want to output a newline rather than a blank.  That would mean that the file is a text file (removing multiple blanks from a binary file is a less plausible operation).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can't see the forest for the trees!! Good point! Just wanted to add the caveat for the OP's info... :-)

Comment: *count* is used as a flag, not as a counter. As a counter it could overflow. Veeerrry extreme situation, but it doesn't hurt to just do "count=1" or, better, "space_found=1".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica True 'nuff... Changed the code. Thanks... :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I do not understand why the value of c is not ' ' after the program exits the if statement

The program enters the body of the `if` block only in the event that `c == ' '`, but *inside that block*, the inner `while` loop reads new values for `c`, one at a time, until `c` is set to a value different from `' '`.  Therefore, when control leaves that inner `while` loop, `c` is guaranteed to *not* contain a `' '`.

You argue,

> if the value of c is ' ' when the if statement starts, and if it is ' ' in the second while loop, it should also be ' ' when both exit, but this does not appear to be the case.

The problem with that logic is the "if it is ' ' in the second while loop".  That's at best imprecise. What matters for this purpose is not the value of `c` in the body of the loop (especially for your empty loop), but rather the value of `c` after the last time the loop's condition is evaluated -- which will be the first time that it evaluates to false.  `c` is updated every time that expression is evaluated.  This equivalent form for that loop would be clearer:

```
            do {
                c = getchar();
            } while (c == ' ');
```

Comment: Note also that your function is flawed: it will output an unexpected extra character if the input ends with one or more space characters. This is because the check for `EOF` is performed only for the characters read by the earlier `getchar()` call, not for the ones emerging from the inner `while` loop.

Comment: See my comment below the OP above (just to draw your attention to something).

Comment: Well, @LoverofStructure, I am among those who have a copy of K&R (1st edition!) on my shelf, but to the extent that the tag in question is about the book, as opposed to about the version of C that the first edition describes, I entirely agree with those who find the tag inappropriate for SO.

Comment: Ah I see the flaw in my logic, that it exits the second while loop precisely because the value of c is no longer ' '. I will need some more time to process the second flaw in the code, though thank you for drawing my attention to it.

Comment: Well ... I think we should have 2 separate tags, one for the book (2nd edition) and one for K&R C, as described in the 1st edition. But somehow things got merged in the past, and I don't know if they ever made such a clean distinction. I mean, the number of books that are *that* often quoted isn't that large: K&R, the dragon book, the Gang of Four, SICP (but no one ever asks about Lisp/Scheme here), and apparently we have a small tag for Scott Meyers' Effective C series.

Comment: @LoverofStructure I'm also fascinated by the can of worms I have opened by my apparently innocent use of an existent tag, but I will bear it in mind if I ask questions in future connected to my journey through K&R

Comment: @harlandski No, you didn't open it, it was me who opened it. (But ... enjoy the show!)